# If Block is firing both If and Else statements

Tags: vb.net

I'm having an issue that I feel should be fairly simple but turns out I can't get it to work.  I'm sure it's something that I am doing but I need your expert help.  I'm simply cycling through a datatable and checking to see if a value shows up again in a different column of the datatable.  For some reason BOTH statements are firing and the else statement is overwriting the If statement.

```
For i = 0 To length - 1
        For j = 0 To length - 1
            If Trim(dt.Rows(i)(0)) = Trim(dt.Rows(j)(6)) Then
                need_dt.Rows(i)(9) = "COMP"
                need_dt.Rows(i)(10) = Format(resource.AddWorkingDays(need_dt.Rows(i)(2), -5), "MM/dd/yy")
            Else
                need_dt.Rows(i)(9) = "TOP"
                need_dt.Rows(i)(10) = Format(resource.AddWorkingDays(need_dt.Rows(i)(2), -16), "MM/dd/yy")
            End If
            If Year(need_dt.Rows(i)(10)) = 2029 Then need_dt.Rows(i)(10) = Format(resource.AddWorkingDays(Now, 14), "MM/dd/yyyy")
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Welcome to So! Can you post example data also?  For readability use for each loop where you can, also instead of using index to access the columns, use column name. For example myRow("myColumn"). For searching rows inside the datatable, you could do it without the loop with [select-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) or with Linq.

Comment: My first guess is that on one of the iterations of `j` that `Trim(dt.Rows(i)(0))` <> `Trim(dt.Rows(j)(6))` whereas it does on the another hence both are appearing to "fire"

Comment: Try making the inner loop as For j = i + 1 To length - 1.

Answer (score 2):

The else statement will be executed on all rows that aren't found. You need to keep the result in a variable and do the action you want at the end. Since the other If statement doesn't use j, you don't need to do it on every j.

```
For i = 0 To length - 1
        Dim isFound As Boolean = False

        For j = 0 To length - 1
            If Trim(dt.Rows(i)(0)) = Trim(dt.Rows(j)(6)) Then
                isFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If isFound Then
            need_dt.Rows(i)(9) = "COMP"
            need_dt.Rows(i)(10) = Format(resource.AddWorkingDays(need_dt.Rows(i)(2), -5), "MM/dd/yy")
        Else
            need_dt.Rows(i)(9) = "TOP"
            need_dt.Rows(i)(10) = Format(resource.AddWorkingDays(need_dt.Rows(i)(2), -16), "MM/dd/yy")
        End If


        If Year(need_dt.Rows(i)(10)) = 2029 Then need_dt.Rows(i)(10) = Format(resource.AddWorkingDays(Now, 14), "MM/dd/yyyy")
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want set column number 9 = "COMP" if value of column 0 exists in column 6 of any row.

In this case your problem is -> if last value of column 6 in last row is not equal to value of column 1 - value of column 9 will be overwritten with "TOP"

In your code you need exit from loop after you find equal value.

But I suggest to use little bid more readable approach

```
For Each row As DataRow in need_dt.Rows
   Dim firstColumnValue As String = row.Field(Of String)("0ColumnName").Trim() 

   Dim is6ColumnContainValue As Func(Of DataRow, Boolean) = 
       Function(dtRow) dtRow.Field(Of String)("6ColumnName").Trim() = firstColumnValue

   Dim isValueFound = need_dt.AsEnumerable().Any(is6ColumnContainValue)

   Dim tenthColumnValue AS Date = row.Field(Of Date)("10ColumnName")
   Dim workingDaysToAdd As Integer

   If IsValueFound = True Then
       row.SetField("9ColumnName", "COMP")
       workingDaysToAdd = -5
   Else
       row.SetField("9ColumnName", "COMP")
       workingDaysToAdd = -16
   End If           

   If TenthColumnValue.Year = 2029 Then
       tenthColumnValue = resource.AddWorkingDays(Date.Now, 14)
   Else
       tenthColumnValue = resource.AddWorkingDays(tenthColumnValue, workingDaysToAdd)
   End If

   row.SetField("10ColumnName", tenthColumnValue)
Next
```

Also suggest to set `Option Strict On` which give compile time feedback about possible type conversion errors

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it was just me missing something obvious.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.